# Python Flask SqlAlchemy: database not being queried

Tags: python-2.7, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to get a list of *ids* to the Javascript layer. All that is coming through is the SQL statement.

Independent function:

```
def mcHmos():
    return {hmo.id from hmo in Hmo.query.filter(Hmo.medicaid_proof == True)}
```

In render template I have:

```
return render_template('edit_form.html',
    .....,
    hmoMedProof=mcHmos(),
    ....,
    ....)
```

The template file has the following:

```
 var hmoMedProof = {{hmoMedProof}};
```

When I View Source, I get

```
           var hmoMedProof = SELECT hmo.id as hmo_id 
FROM hmo
WHERE hmo.medicaid_proof = 1;
```

How do I get the results of the query instead of the (raw) SQL?
There are other queries that are working on this page that come from the controller to the template.

Comment: `from` in `{hmo.id from hmo in Hmo.query.filter(Hmo.medicaid_proof == True)}` doesn't seem as a correct construct. Did you mean `for`? Could you provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example?

Comment: Is that the wrong syntax, such that if change that line to `return Hmo.query(id).filter(medicaid_proof is True)` I will get actual database results?

Answer (score 0):

To get the query to execute against the database you must call one of the functions that resolve queries into result sets.

Examples are `.one()`, `.first()`, `.all()`

```
Hmo.query.first()
Hmo.query.filter(Hmo.medicaid_proof == True).all()
```

The query doesnt execute immediately since it can still be composed with other queries later, or have additional filters applied, eg:

```
someQueryObject = Hmo.query.filter(Hmo.medicaid_proof == True)
results = someQueryObject.filter(Hmo.another_column == False).all()
```